# Elliptic surfaces with different Kodaira symbols

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, surfaces, elliptic-surfaces

Are there examples of surfaces $E$ of Kodaira dimension one that have two elliptic fibrations $p,q:E\to C$ over some curve $C$ such that $p$ has semi-stable fibres but $q$ has an additive fibre?

Can this be done with $C\cong \mathbb P^1$?

Comment: At least in characteristic not 2 or 3 this is impossible: the elliptic fibration is unique for Kodaira dimension 1. For char 2 or 3 you may have to consider quasi-elliptic fibrations, and I haven't thought through it.

Comment: That answers my question (in which I should have emphasized that I work in characteristic zero). Thank you very much.